# How can i get mouse position click on terrain?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The camera that the script is attached to is above high the terrain look on the terrain from the top. And now when i click the mouse i'm getting List points. But now i want to make that when i click the mouse it will give me the position on the terrain including terrain high places like hills.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GetMousePosition : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool isMousePressed;
    private List<Vector3> pointsList;
    private Vector3 mousePos;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        isMousePressed = false;
        pointsList = new List<Vector3>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            isMousePressed = true;
            pointsList.RemoveRange(0, pointsList.Count);
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            isMousePressed = false;
        }

        if (isMousePressed)
        {            
            mousePos = GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            mousePos.z = 0;
            if (!pointsList.Contains(mousePos))
            {
                pointsList.Add(mousePos);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Top View Camera]

Comment: The term you want to search for is *raycast*.

Comment: Thanks got it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do this with a [Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html), you can cast a ray from the camera position to the terrain and then get all of the details you desire using the data that you get back.

So in your case if you wanted to add the hit point to the list you would do something like this

```
float distance = 100f;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        isMousePressed = true;
        pointsList.RemoveRange(0, pointsList.Count);
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        isMousePressed = false;
    }

    if (isMousePressed)
    {            
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;

         if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, distance)) 
         {
             if(!pointsList.Contains(hit.point)
             {
                 pointsList.Add(hit.point); 
             }           
         }    
    }
}
```

It should be noted in the above example that Physics.Raycast has many overloads which allow you to customise how the ray fires. You can also use the hit and ray variables to get much more information such as the specific collider it hit as well as the world position at which the ray originated from, more information on how to do just that can be found in the Unity API documentation page for the [Physics Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html).

If you'd like to learn more about Raycasting I'd recommend watching the [official Unity video](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/raycasting) on the topic which goes into further detail, you'll be using it a lot in game development so it's worth learning as much as you can about it before moving forward.